# WCF client failes to authenticate Java web service. Cannot find a token authenticator for the X509SecurityToken

Tags: wcf, authentication, ssl, wss

I created WCF client that integrates Java WS. The idea is quite easy. I should sign my request with client's certificate and the server should return signed response. Signed by server's private key. All communications runs over SSL.

I enabled .NET tracing and I can see that my request is processed successfully and that the response is received. Unfortunately I received the following exception:

> Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token type.

I found a Yaron [blog](http://webservices20.blogspot.si/2010/10/wcf-cannot-find-token-authenticator.html) and he proposed a solution that does not work me.

Here is my client configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
    <source propagateActivity="true"  name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All" logKnownPii="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source propagateActivity="true"  name="System.ServiceModel.IdentityModel" switchValue="All"  logKnownPii="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source propagateActivity="true"  name="System.ServiceModel.Activation" switchValue="All"  logKnownPii="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source  name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"  switchValue="All"  logKnownPii="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
        name="xml" traceOutputOptions="None">
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2">
      <listeners>
        <add name="xml"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logKnownPii="true" logMalformedMessages="false"
                logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                />
            <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
                messageFlowTracing="true" />
        </diagnostics>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="https://www.server.com/ws"
          behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateBehaviour" binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="appCustomBinding" contract="ws.services"
          name="app-servicesSOAP" >

        </endpoint>
      </client>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="appCustomBinding">
                    <security allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
                        authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="false" 
                        securityHeaderLayout="Lax" allowInsecureTransport="false"
                        messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" protectTokens="false"
                        messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                        requireSignatureConfirmation="false" />
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                    <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Digest" transferMode="Buffered"
                        requireClientCertificate="true" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="clientCertificateBehaviour">
            <clientCredentials>
              <clientCertificate findValue="CLIENT_CERT" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
              <serviceCertificate>
                <defaultCertificate findValue="SERVER_CERT" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
              </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And the response I am receiving is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-14514880453351538613570">
                <wsu:Created>2015-12-30T15:07:25Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-12-30T15:12:25Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-14501832448541055407999">MASASIFIjCCB.......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="XWSSGID-1450183244852-860467203">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse SOAP-ENV"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#XWSSGID-14514880453351164099649">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                <ds:XPath>./SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Header/wsse:Security/ds:Signature[1]/ds:KeyInfo/wsse:SecurityTokenReference</ds:XPath>
                            </ds:Transform>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#STR-Transform">
                                <wsse:TransformationParameters>
                                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                </wsse:TransformationParameters>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>5kmj7l.....</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#XWSSGID-14514880453351538613570">
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>GssfNgXcx....</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>zcfVW....</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-1451488045318234803139">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#XWSSGID-14501832448541055407999" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-14514880453351164099649">
        body content
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The exception i received should indicate that the certificate is incorrectly referenced but I do not see anything to be wrong in the response. Is this WCF related issue?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try authenticationMode of "mutualCertificate", set ProtectionLevel.Sign on the contract, and posisbly also allowSerializedTokenOnResponse=true. Some more information here: https://gist.github.com/yaronn/6775810

Comment: Hi Yaron. Indeed this pushed me a step further!! I got the following issue now: "The incoming message was signed with a token which was different from what used to encrypt the body", so it looks like one more certificate is used for the signature.... I will investigate this further to figure out how to implement this now and let you know. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Apparently I did use a wrong service certificate. I am using the proper one now and i made another step forward. I am almost done, but the error: Unsupported transform or canonicalization algorithm (System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage) is blocking me. I get the similar response on SoapUI returns the similar error: The SIG_TRANSFORM Algorithm attribute has an incorrect value. It is something on the provider side, that i can not understand.

Comment: how does the soap response look like now? this error might mean the response uses a non standard signature algorithm in which case wcf might not be able to verify it.

Comment: I could not found anything unusual maybe your eye will catch something: http://pastie.org/private/p9ux1skxdmlsxtj9jp7w  and here is the full exception http://pastie.org/private/2musklgpwqvo3xhpfcb4nq

Comment: the response uses this (rare) signature algorithm http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116 which wcf seem not to support. it is best if you can ask the service author to change it to something more common. otherwise you might be able to manually validate the signature with SignedXml and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.xmldsigxpathtransformurl(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Yaron. I really appreciate your help. It seems I will have to do this manually then, as the change of algorithm would have impact on the production.